# get the differences between 2 Integer columns into third column

Tags: excel, vba

I have to calculate the difference between the values of 2 columns(firstCol and lastCol) and set those differences in a different column(NextColumn). The row count keeps changing, so I have to calculate the rowCount before calculating the difference. I'm trying to write a loop using Range so that the difference can be calculated but it doesn't seem to work.

```
For i = 3 To lastRow

Range(Cells(3, NextColumn), Cells(lastRow, NextColumn)).FormulaR1C1 = "=Range(Cells(i, firstCol),Cells(i,firstCol)).Value - Range(Cells(i, lastCol),Cells(i,lastCol)).Value"

Next i
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any input of "i" into the formula, you need to use " & i & " when using using a formula="", such as:

```
"=A" & i & "+B" & i
```

When you change to just a formula that doesn't input a formula to the cell (math happens in VBA), you can ignore the Excel formatting and "" blocking, such as:

```
= Cells(i,"A").Value +  Cells(i,"B").Value
```

Make sure to use your loop variable where appropriate, so that you would have an outcome in a loop like:

```
Dim i as Long
For i = 1 to 10
    Cells(i,"C").Formula = Cells(i,"A").Value + Cells(i,"B").Value
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you, Cyril! This actually worked pretty well. I didn't see that the variable was in the " " , and wasn't behaving as a variable. I had to correct my loop too. appreciate your help!      ~Nick

Answer (score 0):

Why looping ? Unless I misunderstood the question, something like this should do the trick:

```
Range("X3:X"& lastrow).Formula = "=C3-D3"
```

The formula will adjust.

Answer (score 0):

vba needs to be outside the quotes and you do not need the loop:

```
Range(Cells(3, NextColumn), Cells(lastRow, NextColumn)).Formula = "=" & Cells(3, firstCol).Address(0, 0) & "-" & Cells(3, lastCol).Address(0, 0)
```

No loop needed.  Excel will change the relative references as needed.